# Representation formula for the solution to the Cauchy problem of the porous media equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, parabolic-pde

An exercise in the textbook "Partial Differential Equations (Second Edition by Emmanuele DiBenedetto), page 172: Show that if $m> 1$, possible solutions to the Cauchy problem
\begin{align}\nonumber
%\label{eqn: T1 and f1 relation}
u_t-\Delta u^m&=0 \;\,\text{in}\;\, \mathbb{R}^N\times (0,T],\ \ u\ge0\\ \notag
u(\cdot,0)&=u_0\in C(\mathbb{R}^N) \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)  \notag
\end{align}
cannot be represented as the convolution of $\Gamma_m$ with the initial datum $u_0$. Here $\Gamma_m$ is the fundamental solution to the porous media equation $u_t=\Delta u^m$. How can we prove this?

When $m=1$, the porous media equation is reduced to the heat equation $u_t=\Delta u$ and the representation formula for the solution is
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\,\pi\,t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u_0(y)\,e^{-\frac{|y-x|^2}{4\,t}}\,dy.  
\end{equation}
It is easy to see that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}u(x,t)=0$ for $t>0$. However, when $m\neq1$, the Cauchy problem cannot have a representation formula for the solution. How can we show that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}u(x,t)=0$ for $t>0$ for $m\neq1$? Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: If it was a convolution it would be linear ...

Comment: Are you asking two questions: (a). Show that a representation formula cannot hold and (b). prove that solutions converge to $0$ for large $x$ values? Is this the case? (a) has been answered @LL3.14. For (b) I am a bit confused as it depends on the initial data. If I choose $u_0=1$ it certainly does not hold true for even $m=1$.